# run method when QPlainTextEdit at a certain length

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a pyqt dialog that takes in a list of data that ends in a return (from a barcode scanner that has an auto return.)

The list is 5 items in length and currently I have to click "Add data" to run the `populate_row` method when 5 items are entered.

I split the string into a list using `\n` and deal with each item as needed.

Is there a way I can automate pressing the `add data` button when the number of lines or the number of `\n` reaches 5 in the `QPlainTextEdit` box?

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Status(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Status, self).__init__(parent)

        self.label = QLabel()

        self.btn = QPushButton("Input Data")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.populate_row)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.resize(660, 260)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def populate_row(self, letter):
        self.dialog = QDialog()

        self.dialog.resize(660, 260)

        self.textBox = QPlainTextEdit(self.dialog)

        Rbtn = QPushButton("Add Data")
        Rbtn.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.enter_data(self.textBox.toPlainText()))

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.dialog)
        layout.addWidget(self.textBox)
        layout.addWidget(Rbtn)

        self.dialog.exec_()

    def enter_data(self, text):
        self.label.setText(text)

        lst = text.split("\n")
        try:
            for  x in lst:
                if x != "":
                    print(x)
                    self.do_something_with_x()
        except IndexError:
            pass

        self.update_data()

        self.dialog.close()

    def do_something_with_x(self):
        print('Something done with x..')

    def update_data(self):
        print('Data updated..')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Status()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count the line breaks use the [`blockCountChanged()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#blockCountChanged) signal, and if you want to click on the button you must use the [`click()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#click) method. Also to verify that a string is empty, it is enough with if x: since the strings are iterable and the if iterable returns False if it is empty, and True in other cases.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Status(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Status, self).__init__(parent)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Input Data")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.populate_row)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.resize(660, 260)


    def populate_row(self, letter):
        self.dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.dialog.resize(660, 260)
        self.textBox = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()
        self.textBox.blockCountChanged.connect(self.blockCount)
        self.Rbtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add Data")
        self.Rbtn.clicked.connect(self.runcode)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.dialog)
        layout.addWidget(self.textBox)
        layout.addWidget(self.Rbtn)
        self.dialog.exec_()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def blockCount(self, num):
        if num > 5: self.Rbtn.click()

    def runcode(self):
        self.enter_data(self.textBox.toPlainText())

    def enter_data(self, text):
        self.label.setText(text)
        for  x in text.split("\n"):
            if x:
                print(x)
                self.do_something_with_x()
        self.update_data()
        self.dialog.close()

    def do_something_with_x(self):
        print('Something done with x..')

    def update_data(self):
        print('Data updated..')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Status()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

> void QPlainTextEdit::blockCountChanged(int newBlockCount)
>
> This signal is emitted whenever the block count changes. The new block count is passed in newBlockCount.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *

class Status(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Status, self).__init__(parent)

        self.label = QLabel()

        self.btn = QPushButton("Input Data")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.populate_row)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.resize(660, 260)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def populate_row(self, letter):
        self.dialog = QDialog()

        self.dialog.resize(660, 260)

        self.textBox = QPlainTextEdit(self.dialog)
        #
        self.textBox.blockCountChanged[int].connect(self.blockCount)  # +++
        
        

        Rbtn = QPushButton("Add Data")
        Rbtn.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.enter_data(self.textBox.toPlainText()))

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.dialog)
        layout.addWidget(self.textBox)
        #layout.addWidget(Rbtn)                                       # ---

        self.dialog.exec_()
## +++
    def blockCount(self, num):
        if num > 5:
            self.enter_data(self.textBox.toPlainText())
##

    def enter_data(self, text):
        self.label.setText(text)
        lst = text.split("\n")
        try:
            for  x in lst:
                if x != "":
                    print(x)
                    self.do_something_with_x()
        except IndexError:
            pass

        self.update_data()

        self.dialog.close()

    def do_something_with_x(self):
        print('Something done with x..')

    def update_data(self):
        print('Data updated..')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Status()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]